# JSF: handleNavigation, dispatch, setView not working in PhaseListener

Tags: jsf-2.2, forwarding, phaselistener

I'm desperatly trying to write a JSF phase listener running before RESTORE_VIEW which forwards to different pages depending on login state, permanent login state, requestes view, etc... It's a bit complicated but to ease all up, none of the following trys forwards correctly:

This one seems to work only if there is also a navigation case in faces-config as it ends up with "... no navigation case found ..."

```
String path = "/user/login.xhtml";
FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext(); // PhaseEvent event;

context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, null, path);
```

Same thing with the following:

```
context.getExternalContext().dispatch(path);
```

And in the last one getViewRoot() always returns null:

```
context.getViewRoot().setViewId(path);
```

So how can I forward without defining a navigation case?

It turned out that redirection works:

```
  String requestUrlString = ((HttpServletRequest)(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest())).getRequestURL().toString();
  URL requestUrl = new URL(requestUrlString);
  String linkUrlString = requestUrl.getProtocol() + ":" + "//"
          + requestUrl.getHost() + ":" + requestUrl.getPort()
          + context.getExternalContext().getApplicationContextPath() + "/faces" + path + ".xhtml";
  context.getExternalContext().redirect(linkUrlString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ctx.getExternalContext().redirect(outcome);
ctx.responseComplete();
```

Comment: THANK YOU!
Works perfect for me - but others please be aware that redirect doesn't work with an outcome but needs a full URL.
I changed the posting above how I had to code it.